# Springboot + Postgresql : Error por la tabla en mayusculas

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

Tengo mi tabla en postgresql "Usuarios" y mi dto

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Usuarios")
public class Usuarios {
```

En mi .yml

```
spring:
 datasource: 
  url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tutorial
  username: postgres
  password: 1
 jpa:
  database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
  hibernate:
   naming:
    physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Se supone que la última línea, debería permitir al springboot que ignore las mayusculas.

El error es:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: no existe la relación «usuarios»
  Position: 109
```

Pd: No voy a cambiar el nombre de las tablas.

Comment: Más que cambiar el nombre de las tablas, una de las prácticas que más me ha resultado es no usar camelCase en caso de nombre de tablas o atributos de una entidad en la base. usa "usuarios" o "USUARIOS". Por mi experiencia cuando no usas "" en la creación se hace un downcase del nombre de la tabla, sin embargo cuando los usas considera explícito el nombre de la tabla que pusiste en el create.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si a la hora de crear la tabla se hizo de esta forma:

```
CREATE TABLE Usuarios ...
```

PostgreSQL lo que realmente creó fue la tabla usuarios, sin la mayúscula. Por el contrario si al crear se hizo de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE TABLE "Usuarios" ...
```

Lo tomó como un literal y en tu clase java deberás poner `@Table(name = "\"Usuarios\"")`